# Angular: How to "Save" an "Object"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good Morning, I explain my scenario:

After generating a couple of http calls and after processing them I have a result similar to this:

***xxx.component.ts***

```
nameVariable: any = {};
this.nameVariable = this.createMyObject(params);
console.log(this.nameVariable);
```

Thanks to the *console.log()* we can see that is an ***Object: nameVariable*** like this:

```
Object: { 
   information1: Object {...},
   information2: Array [...],
   information3: Object{...},
   information4: Array[...]
}
```

**How can I save this Object??, 
how do I Save it and then be able to use it within the code and/or use it within a Component?? 
Should use a Model?? what should I study to better understand this thing??**

Comment: what do you mean by save? If you want to store the variable temporarily and access outside of the current component, then you have to either pass them as attributes or use a state management like `ngrx` or `redux`. If you have to store it locally and use it on page reload then you can use `localstorage`

Comment: by "save" I mean an "Object"(I don't know if it's the correct nomenclature) that can be used within:

xxx.component.ts, 
yyy.component.ts, 
zzz.component.ts,

to be able to work on it, read his content even if we are in ppp.componet.ts or within a service, to be able to modify or update it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angular component is a class. The scope of your nameVariable variable is the body of the method where it is defined. You can extend the scope of that variable by introducing it as a field of your class before the constructor of the class as follows:
nameVariable: { (state here the type of the object };
and you may add a prefix like private or public just before the nameVariable word.
Refer to it as this.nameVariable afterwards inside the methods (the const keyword is no more required).

Comment: **xxx.component.ts**

`nameVariable: any = {};
this.nameVariable = this.createMyObject(params);`

in yyy.componet.ts or in zzz.component.ts or in example.service.ts  
**how to use/call/invoked/so dentro a un componet o a un service come fo a legge i i valori di (I am inside a component or a service as I read the values of) "this.nameVariable"??**

Comment: When the nameVariable object is required in other components (just as you are mentioning yyy.component.ts and zzz.component.ts), it can be stored in a service (just as you are mentioning example.service.ts) indeed.

Comment: if i store che value in a model how to view the value in a other component??

Comment: The service itself is a class (say example.service.ts). The nameVariable object can be introduced as a field of the service. Assume the service is refered to as exampleService in some component. Then your object is to be refered to as exampleService.nameVariable.